# How Traceroute can know domain name of Hops?

Tags: ip, icmp, traceroute

I'm studying the ICMP protocol and the tool **traceroute**. I don't understand how can traceroute look up the domain names of Hops if in the ICMP datagram only the IPs can be found. How does it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup), and is basically the opposite of a domain-to-IP lookup.